# Why isn't the iOS browser playing audio from this MP4 video?

Tags: ios, html5-video, mp4

I have 100+ videos encoded in `H.264 video` with `MP3 audio` for a `HTML5-video` project, but the Audio won't work on iOS. (No sound, but working video). It works perfectly on Android. They all have the same encoding setup, but [here's](https://1fichier.com/?h75gujhtyhle1mheq036) one of the videos

Googled for several days and can't seem to find any known problems with `iOS` and MP3-audio. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the ringer of hardware device is turned off.  If you flip the ringer off and on and the audio turns off and on, then that is the cause.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The device's volume is on, and it works with youtube-videos. My best guess is it's related to the audio encoder or something, but that is strange as iOS Safari is supposed to support mp4-videos with mp3-audio. :/